# Change Visual Studio installation folder after install

Tags: visual-studio

I'm running out of space on the partition that has Visual Studio installed. It's safe to copy the installation in another partition?

Answer (score 12):

You could move the files to the new location (manually) and then use Junction (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) to create a link back.  I did that with 2012 and it seems to be working for me.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me! (and with VS 2013) Thanks!

Comment: Great idea, but should you do this, do your future self a favor and tape a giant message to your monitor **"I HAVE JUNCTION"**, so you don't get confused like I did.

Comment: I was trying to do so (vs2022) to have visual studio on my external SSD and MSVS runs but shows this error inside : "The 'Global Hub Client Package' package did not load correctly. The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension." and Reset configs or clearing caches don't work. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/global-hub-client-package-failed-to-load-correctly/1461455

Comment: @Alix, same error. Supposedly fixed in vs2022, v17.3. After updating to v17.3, AND repairing the installation, it now works with the junction.

Answer (score 4):

Without having tried I bet this isn't possible.

Installation folders are typically stored in many places such as config files and the registry. After moving, all these references will still point to the old and now invalid location. And, even worse, moving the folder will also break any installation / uninstallation / update routines which means that you will no longer be able to install patches and service packs.

Conclusion: You are way better off uninstalling Visual Studio and moving it to the new location. It takes only a short time as compared to the headache that you would end up otherwise.

(Or, if you don't like to do that you can of course still mount a new partition to the program files folder to increase disc space or get a larger hard drive)

Comment: On your last point.  How well would windows handle the process of copying eveyrthing in Program Files to a new partition, and then mounting that partition at Program Files?

Comment: I wouldn't see a problem with that as long as you have the same file systems (NTFS) on both partitions and copy *all* files with *all* their attributes.

Comment: (I don't know how NTFS links would behave though)

Comment: If by "takes only a short amount of time" you mean "may not take more than a couple hours" then I agree. :-P (I've got VS2013 Community Edition, which comes as a very small installer that downloads a boatload of data as it installs.)

Answer (score 1):

I tried repairing or modifying it via the installer (add remove programs), because I moved it to another Partition. But nothing, it crashes with weird error reports. 
Uninstalling and reinstalling seems the only choice, but that doesn't work either...

I used a USB Stick, gave it the old HDD label and made a junction like described here:
 https://superuser.com/questions/484061/how-to-create-an-ntfs-junction

```
mklink /J <new directory to be linked> <target directory>

D:\>mklink /J "Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0" "K:\Program Files\Mic
rosoft Visual Studio 11.0"
```

This doesn't work unfortunately because VS still complains about other missing files, but it at least let's you unistall it.

EDIT: If you try to reinstall VS and it won't let you choose a different folder look here at the accepted answer: [How to change Visual Studio 2012 install directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068991/how-to-change-vs11-install-directory)

Comment: mklink worked perfectly for VS 2017 Enterprise as well

no reinstall required

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution, if you've installed it to, say F:, but now want it on the disk that's currently your E:, is to change the drive letter assignments.

1. Copy the Program Files folder on F: to E:
2. Rename F: to G:
3. Rename E: to F:
4. Run Visual Studio to check it works
5. Delete ProgramFiles on G:
   Not such a neat solution as using hard links, but once it's done there's no long-term side effects other than all your other files on those drives suddenly moving.

Answer (score -1):

No, that wouldn't work with any newer versions of Visual Studio. If it's pre-2003 you might have a chance.