# How to reinstall VS 2012 to different directory?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've installed VS in "Old folder". Now I've uninstalled VS and deleted "Old folder" and want to reinstall it to "New folder".
But when I reinstall VS to "New folder" it says that only 415mb will be installed (too little, seems that something is still stored on my PC) then it installs only some folders to "New folder" and recreates "Old folder" putting there main part of VS again!

I've tried to change permissions of "Old folder" to "Read only", but after that VS just showed error during install. 

P.S: [It's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068991/how-to-change-vs11-install-directory) not the same question

Comment: Did you uninstall VS first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache` folder, or if by any chance your `ProgramData` folder is located elsewhere type `%ProgramData%\Package Cache` in your Run box you'll notice a whole lot of folders and files taking over 2GB of space. 
That is where the VS 2012 data is stored and that is where it is getting the data from when you install to a different location.

Deleting the 'Old Folder' was therefore a bad idea because not all VS 2012 files were stored there, you must first uninstall VS 2012 which will remove the 'Old Folder' AND the `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache` at which point you can install into 'New Folder' and while VS 2012 installation will again copy all those files to the same folder it will also fix all the registy entries to point to your 'New Folder' instead.

Alternatively, you could do a search and replace in your registry but I suspect that would take more time and/or effort than uninstalling from the old location and installing into new loacation.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I've previously uninstalled VS. I've fixed it in my question. But now I'll try to uninstall VS, delete Package Cache manually (VS didn't delete it automatically) and notice what will happen

Comment: So, now (after deleting "Package Cache" installer required 1.49Gb, but some folders still were installed in "Old folder" ("Common7", "VC", "Xml"), also it recreated "workspace" folder and VS isn't starting. Then I tried "Repair" -> it showed "Setup Completed" but with error "Microsoft Windows Operating System" The event log file is full.". Now VS is starting but installer also recreated all folders in "Old Folder" again =/

Comment: Looks like you'll have to uninstall, delete the Package Cache and than get rid of any entries in the registry with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0" or whatever was the "OldPath"...

Comment: You were right. Just one additional step: after these procedures install failed with lots of errors, so I've uninstalled it forcibly (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2771441/en-us#Force), than installed again -  now it's ok