# Installing Visual Studio on another drive

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I will be getting another pc where drive C: will be SSD and the rest of the drives HDD. The SSD size is significantly smaller so I don't want it to get full from just codes and Visual Studio stuff.

I came across this guide:

http://www.placona.co.uk/1196/dotnet/installing-visual-studio-on-a-different-drive/

but at the bottom, it says that it's not a permanent solution because updates will still get installed in drive C:

I haven't tried this yet but:

1. does the latest version of visual studio allow you to install on another drive?
2. would it be better if I create a VM (on another drive) then install Visual Studio there? any downside on developing while in a VM?

Comment: IMHO it makes sense to install it on the SDD along with your project to profit from the increased access speed when accessing many small files (the VS headers are in the installation folders). Which happens a lot when compiling. I know this is not an answer but rather a reason why you should rethink your intentions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Visual Studio 2015 on a different drive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029751/how-to-install-visual-studio-2015-on-a-different-drive)

Comment: Did you try using /d instead of /j?