# How can I install Visual Studio 2017 on an external drive?

Tags: visual-studio, local-storage

For the life of me I've tried every hack there is to install Visual Studio on my system with only 13 GB free space on Drive C. Windows is installed on Drive C, so that's justified. I have about 400 GB free on Drive D but I just cannot get VS to download over there. I've changed the path, but even so it gives me an error for insufficient disk space. I don't know what to do. I've used some regedit hack to have Program Files on Drive D but VS just doesn't follow that flow. I'm lowkey a noob so please help.

Comment: Does '"I've changed the path" mean you changed the installation path during VS installation?

Comment: Yes exactly that

Comment: Maybe this is helpful [How to install Visual Studio on a different drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029751/how-to-install-visual-studio-2015-on-a-different-drive). This gives a guide to install it from the command line. Although it seems that VisualStudio allways forces to install the majority of the files to Drive C.

Comment: The easiest way is taking some space from your D: drive and expanding C: using a program like Partition Wizard.

Comment: Do you have more then just windows installed on the C:/ Drive? Is this a 40gb SSD or something? If you have other applications installed on the C:/ Drive it might be easier to uninstall then reinstall them to another drive to create enough room for Visual Studio. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e7160ef-505e-4c48-a1aa-78e778c13ee0/install-visual-studio-2017-in-d-drive?forum=vssetup  "This won't change location of all files, but only of those which can be (by design) installed onto different location."

Comment: Probably actually a problem with the installer, it stores the packages it downloads in c:\programdata.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2017/04/17/moving-or-disabling-the-package-cache-for-visual-studio-2017/