# XAML Designer System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows, xaml-designer

- I'm encountering the following
  System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException error when I create a blank
  Windows 10 Universal Application...

  [image: Error on Visual Studio]

  Following are event viewer screens... [image: Event Viewer]

  [image: Event Viewer]

  I have checked online for other solutions and have already done the
  following...

  - Uninstall/Repair Visual Studio 2015 Update 1
  - Reset my Windows 10 PC 1511 update
  - Cleared the Designer/ShadowCache folder
  - Target environment has been set to x86/x64
  - Target framework set to 10240
  - Developer mode enabled
  - Updated graphic drivers
  - Have cleaned and rebuilt solution
  - Updated to VS15 Update 2

Please let me know if you have been able to find a solution to the above

Comment: Cant say its the same exception, but I get an exception frequently when viewing the XAML designer in VS2015.  To resolve it I usually try 3 things:  1.  Click the link to reload it.  2.  Close the file, recompile, then open it again, or 3.  Clean the project, then try 1 & 2 again.

Comment: Also, it looks like an UnAuth exception is happening, I would make sure you are running VS as an administrator.

Comment: @Mike_G yea I have tried the steps the way you have mentioned and I still can't get it to work. And yes VS is running in Administrator mode.

The xaml designer doesn't work for me at all even if its a blank project that is compiling correctly.

Comment: Was a solution ever found here? I'm experiencing the same thing on one PC. XAML Designer will crash within seconds with the above mentioned Remoting issue. On another PC I have no issue with the exact same project. I've found no solution so far but am hoping that Update 2 will be announced @ //Build in a few days and might and provide a fix.

Comment: I have installed Update 2 and subsequently also cleared up my shadowcache. Unfortunately still face the exact same error !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been a few months but I have finally been able to get the XAML Designer to work.
As @peterfaraday mentioned, the XAML Designer only works if you install Visual Studio on the System Drive (C: in my case) instead of using any other drive.
After uninstalling Visual Studio keep the following things in mind...

- **If your system partition is small,** look to increase the space as the installation can take a lot of space based on the components selected.
- **If you had already installed VS on any other drive,** while reinstalling you will not be able to change the default installation directory.

This is because your initial path of installation was saved as in the registry. I tried solving this issue by following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12162313/1642932). In my case I had found multiple keys in the registry and hence "Reset this PC" (Windows 10) by allowing only for my personal files to remain. This cleared out all the registry keys and I was able to install VS back on the C: drive, resulting in the XAML Designer finally working *(Please note that resetting your pc will remove any applications installed on your machine)*

Answer (score 3):

UWP applications fail to launch from Visual Studio if project location and Windows Store apps installation path are on a non-default drive. Also, the XAML Designer will crash if you install Visual Studio and Windows Store apps to a non-default drive

Windows 10 allows users to change the default storage location of Windows Store applications. If you select a non-default drive for your apps, and if you install Visual Studio 2015 onto this drive, the XAML designer will not start and Windows Store app projects built on this drive cannot be run from Visual Studio.

Note: the workaround below will make any Store apps installed to the secondary drive inaccessible until next restart.

The file system driver can be temporarily disabled by running the following command from an admin command prompt:

fltmc detach filecrypt :

This will enable both running apps from this drive as well as usage of the XAML designer until the machine is restarted.

For a longer term fix, move your app or Visual Studio install to your system drive, or a secondary drive that has never been the storage location for Windows Store apps.

Comment: I installed Visual Studio on my System Drive (C:) and the XAML designer finally works, thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I started visual studio as an administrator and the designer came back.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to [clear the XAML Designer Shadow Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35780402/4140832). I've fixed al sorts of ailments with this process.

Comment: I've upgraded to VS 2015 update 2 as well and I don't have the issue any longer. Then again, I've also made a number og changes to the code since I last tried on the PC that was failing.

Comment: well even creating a blank new app also results in that error for me

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem months ago. I Cleared the cache and Rebuild the solution. I got success.

Comment: That's already what Jasper Hedegaard Bojsen said in the other answer. When you answer, please include new information.