# Visual Studio 2017 Pro - XAML Designer crashes by create a new Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, exception, visual-studio-2017

since a few days i have the problem if i create a new wpf project in Visual Studio 2017 Pro the XAML Designer crashed with an exception like this:

*System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException
[] Der Designerprozess wurde unerwartet beendet.
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IIsolationDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String assemblyCodeBase, String typeName)
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationDomainFactory isolationDomainFactory, IObjectCatalog catalog)
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationDomainFactory domainFactory)
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationDomainFactory domainFactory, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken) bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.b__0()
bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()*

No Solution i have found on the Web works for me...
I have uninstalled Visual Studio, uninstalled all SDK's and installed Visual Studio after reboot but nothing works...

Has Anybody an idea for me

Comment: Is it fully updated?  you can start VS is safemode, if that works its likely an corrupt extension, if not you might need to do a repair or reinstall. Also if this is Core Wpf, i think its still a little buggy

Comment: How i can start in save mode?

Comment: `devenv.exe /SafeMode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution for this Issue works. I've done the following steps:

- i uninstalled VS 2017
- i uninstalled all SDK's
- i clean up and delete all Visual Studio Folders in c:\program and c:\program x86 and in user\appdata and so on
- i have clean up the registry and delete all entries by "Visual Studio"
- after this i installed Visual Studio 2017 on my "D" Drive

An now it works fine...

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps I would take:

1. Make sure your Visual Studio is fully up-to-date
2. Start Visual Studio in [safe mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) `devenv.exe /SafeMode` (this loads only the default environment and services.)

   - 2.1 If that works it's likely a corrupted extension. try and uninstall some of your extensions, and third-party tools
   - 2.1 You can also check the VS [logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms241272(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) `Devenv /log LogFile`, this might give you more information about the error
3. Repair visual studio
4. Reinstall visual studio

If you are fully updated and still can't get it to work, I would consider making a bug report with Visual Studio.

[How to report a problem with Visual Studio or Visual Studio Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Sorry, but all this steps wasn't helpfull... any other ideas?

Comment: All? Or select steps?

Comment: @RenéKolbe if nothing works (which I don't belive) you need to talk to the vender. This should happen, it doesn't happen for me, or lots of other people. It's thr software or your environment, or both

Comment: Hi @all,
now i give up... I've uninstall the VS2017 completly, ihave deleted all Files and Folders after uninstall, i have clean up the registry manualy and uninstall all SDK's... then i have installed the VS 2017 clean but always the same :-(
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I found some methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544465/xaml-designer-system-runtime-remoting-remotingexception). If it can't solve your problem, you could report this problem in the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).